# Configure SQL server to store session state

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, session-state, windows-server-2012

I am trying to set up session state in SQL server.

Command:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe -ssadd –sstype c -d SomeName -S SERVERNAME -U someUser -P somePass
```

It throws: ***The argument '-sstype' is invalid.***

Any tips?

Comment: Have you enabled `Agent XPs`??

Comment: Still the same error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stupid.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe -ssadd -d SomeName -S SERVERNAME -U someUser -P somePass –sstype c
```

The arguments order...

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Agent XPs` to run `Aspnet_regsql.exe tool`

From [Installing the Session State Database Using the Aspnet_regsql.exe Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.ASPX)

> By default, you cannot use the Aspnet_regsql.exe tool to install the session state database on SQL Server Express. In order to run the Aspnet_regsql.exe tool to install a SQL Server Express database, you must first enable the Agent XPs SQL Server option using Transact-SQL commands like the following:

---

```
EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXECUTE sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXECUTE sp_configure 'show advanced options', 0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

Comment: Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'Agent XPs' changed from 1 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.
Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 0. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install. /// Still same error.