# vs2012 IIS Express:sessionState Mode SQLServer or StateServer throws runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I want to store session  for using  stateServer  or  SqlServer  mode,so I add node in web.config file.but the error  happened.how could I do?
I started my project with  vs2012 debug mode.

> Runtime Error
>   Description: An exception occurred while processing your request. Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

```
<system.web>
<sessionState mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="data source=localhost;user id=sa;password=123456" cookieless="false" timeout="10" />
<system.web>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure SQL server to store session state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634044/configure-sql-server-to-store-session-state)

Comment: @JonEgerton Sir thanks, but I  don't think  your solution can solve my  problem,cuz whatever **SqlServer  Mode** or **StateServer Mode** will  fire the same exception.